# How can I make a UIButton perform my class method when tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, uibutton, class-method

How can I make a UIButton perform my class method, `+doSomething:(id)sender`, on class `MyClass`, after any event like `UIControlEventTouchDown`?  Can I use `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` like I do for instance methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since classes are also ObjC objects, you can use `-addTarget:...` as usual:

```
[button addTarget:[MyClass class]
           action:@selector(classMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Its crashing with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)" on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Add an in-between method that will call the Class method.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(callClassMethod:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void)callClassMethod:(id)sender {
    [MyClass classMethod:sender];
}
```

Comment: This would work but I want to avoid the inter-dependencies between classes this approach creates.  Any other ideas?